# Application Insight Analytics on long time-period

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I know that Application Insights store data for only some period of time.

What do I need to do if I want to do analysis on a long time-period, let's say a year?

I know we have continuous export thing and as suggested, we can use power BI on the stored data in BLOBs but that will have a cost associated with it. Another way is code and transform that JSON data in BLOBs to some excel representations.

Is there any other way apart from these two for doing analysis in long time-periods of AI data? Something that picks data stored in BLOBs and uses that to show analytics?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things being developed - ability to specify different retention period (1 year will be more expensive) and ability to do analytics query on top of blobs. Unfortunately, both of them are not yet available.

Will be providing updates to this answer.

**Update**: It is possible to specify a retention for Application Insights resources.

Comment: Thanks.I got to know about the retention policy upgrade while looking for this but wasn't aware about the analytics query on blobs which would be a really cool feature :)
Is there any tool that you know of that I can use currently on top of blobs data?

Comment: I don't have good suggestion here. For some data I personally run queries on regular basis and save results in Excel files. Then analyze using Excel built-in functionality. The drawback is that if query needs to be modified - cannot rerun on past data. Export everything and then use other analytics platform is an option - but then need to learn two languages/tools. Yes, I also wait for both features for our own telemetry =)